# CakePHP: is there a way to make every find('list') return an array ordered?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.8

I'd like every `Model->find('list')` could return the array ordered by the `$displayField` set on Model. Is there a way to do this beyond set `'order' => 'Model.display_field ASC'` on every find call?

Comment: can you please share what you done till now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just set `$order` in the model.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#order

Comment: That's it! Thank you! I'm gonna accept the answer soon as possible.

Comment: Glad I could help.